# How to select a primary key which has exact foreign keys matches a given list of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

For example:

```
pk_ref    fk
======    ===
1         a
1         b
1         c
2         a
2         b
2         d
```

How do I do a query like the "pseudo" query:

```
select distinc pk_ref
where fk in all('a', 'c');
```

The return query result must match all given values for the foreign key in the list.

The result should be:

```
1
```

While the following select must not return any records.

```
select distinc pk_ref
where fk in all('a', 'c', 'd');
```

How do I do that?

Comment: are you using SQL Server?

Comment: yes, but if there is standard sql regardless of db engine it will be better.

Comment: How is the "variable" list of fk values passed in? One general approach may be to have a subquery where you select distinct pk, fk where fk in list, and in the outer query you group by pk and count the rows. But for the final filter (HAVING clause) you need to know how many values there are in the list, so you need to be able to count them. So... how is the list given to the query?

Comment: @mathguy the fk list of values will be given as a string by user in application, then the expected query result should be as explained above in question.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
select pk_ref 
from yourtable 
group by pk_ref 
having count(case when fk = 'a',  then 1 end) >= 1 
and count(case when fk = 'c' then 1 end) >= 1
```

To do it dynamically. (considering you are using SQL SERVER)

Create a split string function and pass the input as comma separated values

```
Declare @input varchar(8000)= 'a,c',@cnt int 

set @cnt = len(@input)-len(replace(@input,',','')) + 1

select pk_ref 
from yourtable 
Where fk in (select split_values from udf_splitstring(@input , ','))
group by pk_ref 
having count(Distinct fk) >= @cnt
```

You can create a split string function from the below link

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I have unknown number of values, the list of values is variant.

Comment: @DevX - then you need to use dynamic query

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: No need for dynamic query. Complicated and inefficient. The input string doesn't need to be split, either.

Comment: @mathguy It is Complicated but much efficient than `Like`. Consider you have 10million records with index on `fk` column. Mine will perform much better than yours..

Answer (score 3):

`:list` is the input list (bind variable). The difference of `length()` return values is the number of commas in the bind variable. This query, or something very close to it, should work in pretty much any DB product. Tested in Oracle.

```
select   pk_ref
from     tbl    --  enter your table name here
where    ',' || :list || ','   like   '%,' || fk || ',%'
group by pk_ref
having   count(distinct fk) = 1 + length(:list) - length(replace(:list, ',', ''))
```

Comment: I don't think this is efficient at all. It just looks simple. Leading `%` in `Like` will make the query non sargable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can pass the `IN` operator values as Set, then you can do this as below

Schema:

```
SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM (
SELECT 1 ID, 'a' FK
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'a'
)AS A
```

Used CTE to make 'a','c'  as Set

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 'a' FK   --Here 'a','c' passed as a Set through CTE
UNION 
SELECT 'c'
)
,FINAL AS(

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (FK))AS COUNT_ID, ID, FK 
FROM #TAB where FK  IN (select FK FROM CTE)

)
SELECT ID FROM FINAL WHERE COUNT_ID>=(SELECT COUNT( FK) FROM CTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select pk_ref where fk='a' and pk_ref in (select pk_ref where fk='c' from yourtable) from yourtable;
```

or

```
select pk_ref where fk='a' from yourtable intersect select pk_ref where fk='c' from yourtable;
```

Comment: intersect queries is a perfect answer, but how to make this as a dynamic query, so any number of values can be passed to it, not just for two variables like 'a' and 'c' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @inputVariable VARCHAR(200) =  'a,b,c,d'
    DECLARE @inputValue INT
    DECLARE @tblInput TABLE
    (
        FK VARCHAR(100)
    )




    INSERT INTO @tblInput
    SELECT SUBSTRING( @inputVariable+',',RN,1)
      FROM (SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.object_id) RN
      FROM sys.objects s)  s
      where LEN(@inputVariable) >= RN
      AND SUBSTRING(','+ @inputVariable,RN,1) = ','

    SELECT @inputValue = COUNT(1) FROm @tblInput

    --@inputVariable

    DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
    (
        ID INT,
        FK VARCHAR(100) 
    )

    INSERT INTO @tbl
    SELECT 1 ID, 'a' FK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'c'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'a'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'd'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'a'

    SELECT t.ID ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.FK) 
      FROM @tbl t
    INNER JOIn @tblInput  ti
            ON t.FK = ti.FK
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.FK) = @inputValue
```