# How do I get the count for orders with a certain code only when there are multiple codes for the same order possible

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry this is my first post - please let me know if something doesn't make sense!

I'm trying to get a count of the number of orders with a specific code XXX ONLY

lets say table A looks something like this

```
|ORDER ID | ITEM CODE |
123         XXX    
123         YYY
123         YYY
456         XXX
456         XXX
456         XXX
789         XXX
000         YYY
```

what i want in the output is:

- order 123 and 000 not to count
- and order 456 and 789 to count as 1 each

I only want the count of the unique orders which have item code XXX ONLY

so the count/ output of the final query should be 2

currently what i have is

```
select order_id, item code, count(order_id) from table a
where item code = 'XXX' 
group by order_id, item code
order by count(order_id)
```

which outputs me the following

```
ORDER_ID  | ITEM CODE  |  COUNT(ORDER_ID)
 123        XXX            1
 345        XXX            3
 789        XXX            1
```

This is wrong because I want the output as described above

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a primary key which has exact foreign keys matches a given list of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326359/how-to-select-a-primary-key-which-has-exact-foreign-keys-matches-a-given-list-of). Or [Oracle query to match all values in the list among all rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995405/oracle-query-to-match-all-values-in-the-list-among-all-rows-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an anti-join. For example:

```
select distinct t.order_id, 1 as cnt
from table_a t
left join table_a u on u.order_id = t.order_id and u.item_code <> 'XXX'
where t.item_code = 'XXX' and u.order_id is null
```

Result:

```
 ORDER_ID  CNT 
 --------- --- 
 789       1  
 456       1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bfeff6ab3e89fcbcaa4c0373aa6b2bfa).

**EDIT**

To get the total count only, tweak the query as shown below:

```
select count(distinct t.order_id) as cnt
from table_a t
left join table_a u on u.order_id = t.order_id and u.item_code <> 'XXX'
where t.item_code = 'XXX' and u.order_id is null
```

Result:

```
CNT
---
2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46458726b3f1104ea4f02cad44f1c40c).

Comment: thanks for the quick response and the helpful edit!

so with this output what if i just want the total number of orders with that code ONLY.

The output would be a count of 2

Comment: @datanerd See edit.

Comment: @datanerd I think you should upvote all three answers, since they all comply with your initial question.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! I was unable to upvote because I'm still new. Also as a newbie SQLer can you explain to me exactly how this anti-join works? It definitely did the trick.

Comment: @datanerd An "anti-join" selects rows from the "left" table that do not have a match in the "right" table. It uses an outer join for it. In this case the left table includes the XXX while the right table includes the YYY. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29.

Answer (score 0):

```
select order_id
from table_a
group by order_id
having min(item_code) = 'XXX'
   and max(item_code) = 'XXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want this :

```
select distinct order_id , item_code , 1 as count
from table t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from table t2 
    where t1.order_id = t2.order_id 
    and t2.item_code <> 'XXX'
)
```

the count would be always 1 per your question